# Can i use a filtre in a template in django?

Tags: django, forms, many-to-many

I made a loop allowing me to display for each page questions and answers utilisers.
I wonder if it's possible in the template to "filter" to get only the issues of page 1 for example?

```
<form action="" method="GET">
{{ form.as_p }}


{% for page in pages %}<hr>
    {{ page }}: 

    <br>{% for reply in  page.reply_set.all %}<br> {{ reply.question }} --> {{ reply.answer }} (Author : {{ reply.user }}) {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have a fields ManytoMany so this is what it's hard to understand...

```
class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label


class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Reply(models.Model):
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(),blank=True, verbose_name="Date de création") 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

You can see on this screenshot I have tree pages('name visit 1 visit 2 visit 3) and i want just the first visit what is the loop for get this ? 
[image: the resultt]

The best I would get is the page that I want based on the id

EDIT : views.py

```
def access(request,instance):
    replies = Reply.objects.all()
    questions = Question.objects.values()
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
    pages = Page.objects.all()
    # pagesfilter = Page.objects.get(pk=instance).reply_set.all()
    form = ReplyForm(request.GET)
    personnes = Personne.objects.all()
    if logged_user:
        if len(request.GET) > 0:
            form = ReplyForm(request.GET)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/reply')
            else:
                return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {'pagesfilter':pagesfilter, 'numPages': numPages, 'personnes': personnes, 'replies': replies, 'questions': questions,'pages':pages, 'form': form})
        else:
            form = ReplyForm()
            return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {'pagesfilter':pagesfilter, 'numPages': numPages, 'personnes':personnes, 'replies': replies, 'questions': questions, 'pages':pages, 'form': form})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question, which was closed because it was unclear. It is *still* unclear. If you want to avoid this one being closed, you will need to actually explain your problem, tell us what a "visit" is, and stop posting unreadable screenshots.

Comment: Can you post the view of this page?

Comment: i have edit the views

Answer (score 1):

If you know `visit1` is the first element in the loop you can do:

```
{% for page in pages %}<hr>
  {% if forloop.first %}
   {{ page }}: 

    <br>{% for reply in  page.reply_set.all %}<br> {{ reply.question }} --> {{ reply.answer }} (Author : {{ reply.user }}) {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But the best way, I think, is to get `visit1` in your view through a query and send it then to the template.

**EDIT**

As your view looks

```
numPages = Page.objects.get(pk=instance)
```

gets the `Page` you want. So, in template you could use it:

```
{{ numPage }}
{% for reply in  numPage.reply_set.all %}
    {{ reply.question }}--> {{ reply.answer }}(Author : {{ reply.user }})
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: And Is it possible to do the same just that it does take longer but the first term based on the id in url that is?
I put in my url pk=instance

Comment: @JérémyLegendre as your view is, the `numPages` variable should give you the page you are looking for if the `instance` parameter gets the `id` of the `Page`. Remove the loop from the template and use `numPages` instead of `page` there.